Data recovery on locked LG K10 LTE device with partially-broken screen and unresponsive touch but known PIN
I have the above device with a broken display, for which I know the PIN code for. I can power the device up, but obviously cannot unlock it because of the broken screen. The screen is mangled, but you can sometimes tell what's going on.
I had USB debugging enabled on this device, but ADB doesn't seem to be detecting the device, even though it appears as "LG AndroidNet USB Modem" when I plug it in my Windows PC (I installed LG support tools & the drivers).
Trying to connect to the device via LG Bridge results in the following message:

I've tried third-party tools like Dr.Fone, but they don't seem to connect to the device at all.
I tried connecting with the LGB and listing with ADB in factory reset mode, that also didn't help.
What options do I have left? I want to recover data from this device.

Your phone is from 2018, (release with Android 7) most likely it still uses Full Disk Encryption where you have to enter the PIN/password early in the boot process and then the real booting starts afterwards. That may be the reason why adb is not available. Try to connect a simple USB keyboard and type the PIN+Return blindly. May be then your phone will fully boot.

@Robert Yep, the disk is fully encrypted unless the PIN is entered. I didn't know you could plug in a keyboard, so I'll try that and report back.

@Robert plugging a mouse or keyboard did not work. The phone did not recognize any of the devices I tried (I've tried several). Just to clarify, I used a USB to micro-B USB (which my phone accepts) to plug a PC keyboard.

Is the screen you see really the pre-boot mini-OS for entering the PIN or the regular lock screen? If it is the pre-boot mini-OS then it seems USB-OTG isn't supported. In that case the only way to get access is a fix on hardware level (screen replacement or somehow connect a different digitizer to the phone. Not sure if this is really possible).

Mini-OS. Oh well. Thank you.
